# Import javascript array into MVC

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I have the following javascript:

```json
{
   "presenceDetected":true,
   "timestamp":1571219073514,
   "RegionMap":{
      "0":1,
      "1":0
   },
   "deviceId":" TEST_DEVICE_ID "
}
```

and my current C# MVC class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Presence
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool presenceDetected { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Array RegionMap { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
}
```

And my API method:

```
public void MonitorPresence([FromBody] Presence APresenceData)
{
//Loop thru RegionMap here.
}
```

While this seems to bring in the array - I don't actually get any values.  I am sure its wrong.  There might be 0, 1, or 2+ values within the region map array.

I am not able to change the JSON - how do I build my class to accept the RegionMap array?

Comment: `RegionMap` is not an array it is an object in your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your class, replace Array RegionMap with Dictionary<string,int>

```
[DataContract]
public class Presence
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool presenceDetected { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,string> RegionMap { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<int,int>` might be suitable as well

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you. You are right but let us take the midle Dictionary<string,int>

Comment: The middle is how I think will work best - and it worked perfectly.